# Did Netanyahu publicly criticize Soros (or at least his views)?

Tags: israel, hungary

A [Vox article](https://www.vox.com/world/2018/7/31/17623978/israel-jewish-nation-state-law-bill-explained-apartheid-netanyahu-democracy) seems to imply so:

> And just hours before the nation-state law was passed, Netanyahu met with Hungary’s far-right Prime Minister Viktor Orbán in Israel. The two have bonded over their shared loathing of anything connected to the liberal, Jewish, Hungarian-born financier George Soros, as well as their shared anti-refugee views.

So was there any criticism from Netanyahu directed at Soros or at least specifically against something Soros said? (I know [Orbán uses Soros as a scapegoat in Hungary](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jun/22/hungary-viktor-orban-george-soros); that part of the claim from Vox didn't surprise me.)

Comment: Yes, as existing answer posted. Do you include his children criticizing Soros a valid answer as well?

Comment: Also, for context, here is an article that explains in detail why Netanyahu - and plenty of other pro-Israel people both inside and outside Israel - dislike Soros: https://mosaicmagazine.com/picks/2017/07/what-does-israel-have-against-george-soros-quite-a-lot-actually/

Comment: @user4012: Actually, I should have probably phrased my question wider as to whether Likud or Netanyahu's government did...

Comment: Mentioning Orbán as far-right shows that the writer either doesn't have a clue, or is strongly biased. The definition of how far to the right someone is, is not how much you hate him. Orbán is by all definitions center-right.

Comment: @vsz I would say it's pretty fair for the author to avoid comparisons with other well known center-right heads of state like, for example, Merkel. Orban has shown to be a clearly authoritarian figure to the point that the press is no longer fully free in Hungary. He also justified some very undemocratic behavior with the fuzzy concept of "illiberal democracy" (this includes breaking rule of law principles) and has been seen to support several far-right ideas (inc. anti-immigration,  persecution of opposition, etc.). Calling him center-right is offensive to a great number of people.

Comment: @armatita - since when is anti-immigration and persecution of opposition a "far right" special? Last state I lived in that practiced both was USSR. Not exactly a bastion of the right.

Comment: @user4012 You mean not a bastion of right-side economics. But Russia (USSR even worse) has, indeed, a [far-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far-right_politics) government. Authoritarian stance, nationalism, chauvinism, xenophobia, homophobia, etc. By far-right I'm certainly not speaking about the economy axis (which puts Orban more or less at the center), but the [authoritarian axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_compass). So just to be clear it is perfectly possible for a "far-right" government to be practicing left or right wing economics. No argument there.

Comment: @armatita : the definition of center-right and far-right don't depend upon whether you are personally offended by them or not. Debating your accusations would be off topic here, so I'll only point to the Gyurcsány regime before him, which described itself as left-leaning, and the persecuted opposition in ways Orbán never did (like beating up peaceful protesters, and putting journalists critical to him for months into remand without a trial).

Comment: @vsz The definition of far right I was using is the one I've linked ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far-right_politics)) and the one I would say is most common. You can also use wikipedia to check a general definition of [center-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre-right_politics) politics. The second paragraph of that article (center-right) is particularly effective in saying why Orban should not be considered a center-right politician. You'll probably notice he has far more in common with the far-right article. As for left leaning and right leaning see my comment to user4012.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for skeptics.SE. After all it just asks to confirm a claim in the press. Where is the political question?

Comment: @armatita : both links you cited make it evident that Hungary's current government is center-right. You might cherry-pick a few issues which bother you the most, so that you can name-call them with a label you dislike the most, but it doesn't change the facts. All neutral sources describe them as center-right, those who say far-right are either trying to push an agenda, or have next to no knowledge about the topic, have probably never been to Hungary, and don't know about the conflict between the Fidesz and the Jobbik (which is indeed on the radical right, and around 20% is the second largest)

Comment: @vsz Cherry pick, are you serious? The [EU parl. just voted in favor of sanctions for Hungary](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jun/25/mep-european-parliament-vote-eu-sanction-hungary-viktor-orban), the EU Commission [opened legal proceedings regarding the "Stop Soros" law](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jul/19/brussels-begins-legal-action-against-hungary-over-stop-soros-law), the [freedom of press rating of Hungary is scandalous](https://freedomhouse.org/report/freedom-press/2017/hungary), EPP is considering expelling Fidesz, and so on. What sources do you consider neutral?

Comment: @armatita : and neither of your arguments are proof of them being "far right", you are just using the false equivalence fallacy. Basically all your arguments were in the style of *"I hate fascism, and I hate X. Therefore X is a fascist."*. If you are interested about problems with your citations (and how they are or are not relevant to the question), feel free to continue this in chat, because we are *really* going off topic now.

Comment: @vsz The problem here is that you keep talking about a center right definition without source (which I gave). You talk about neutral sources but produce none (which I did). My point was that you put the article author into question without producing a single source to justify your POV. If your "critique" is in the comments I feel important its debunk also is. Calling Orban center-right at this point in time feels like an attempt to legitimize his actions with the achievements of other people that are nothing like him (or are even against). But this is indeed off topic. Let's wrap this up.

Comment: @armatita : just as an addendum: do you consider Politico and Washington Post as neutral? They both label Orbán as center-right, even in articles which sharply criticize him. And they both lean towards the left, because from your citations it seemed to me you only use/believe leftist sources. So there are the sources for you, and you'll certainly find some more with a little googling.

Comment: @vsz I do read (see) Politico, Guardian, Le Monde, EU Observer, Vox, among others (more rarely the Washington Post, usually only for research). Can you link those articles?

Comment: @Trilarion: "The two have bonded over their shared loathing" sounded a bit hyperbolic, so I was afraid this was gonna get closed on Skeptics where only unambiguous statements are accepted. It was *my interpretation* that meant Netanyahu might have said something publicly about Soros but it doesn't strictly follow from the text quoted. Mods are very picky about stuff like that on Skeptics; over there questions can only be challenging a quoted claim as-is. As to "Where is the political question?" C'mon questions about whether politician X said (or didn't) something about Y are asked here a lot.

Answer (score 10):

[Netanyahu did so in February 2018](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/netanyahu-soros-behind-asylum-seekers-anti-deportation-campaign-1.5787643):

> Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu told Likud ministers on Sunday that Jewish billionaire George Soros is funding a campaign of protest against Israel's plan to deport thousands of African asylum seekers.

He has also [previously](https://www.thejc.com/comment/comment/anshel-pfeffer-attacks-on-george-soros-antisemitism-is-nothing-new-for-israel-s-benjamin-netanyahu-1.458706) - in July 2017 - defended attacks against Soros:

> Last year, when the Jewish community in Hungary – where the Orban government has been waging its own campaign tinged with barely-concealed antisemitism against Mr Soros’ donations to progressive Hungarian groups – appealed to Israel to support its protests against the government, the Israeli ambassador in Budapest responded immediately with a statement supporting them.
>
> However, when Mr Netanyahu, who is also Israel’s acting foreign minister, was informed of the ambassador’s actions, he overturned the statement and directed the Foreign Ministry to clarify that it had not “meant to delegitimize criticism of George Soros, who continuously undermines Israel’s democratically elected governments by funding organizations that defame the Jewish state and seek to deny it the right to defend itself.”

[The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/netanyahu-orb-n-israel-welcome-hungary-prime-minister-antisemitism-a8454866.html) goes into the possible reasons for this:

> But despite accusations Mr Orbán had stoked antisemitism in Europe, he has taken a firm stance in support of Israel at a time when Mr Netanyahu is increasingly looking to European allies as he faces mounting criticism from the EU.

Netanyahus opinion was [not](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/.premium-zeroing-in-on-soros-netanyahu-is-side-by-side-with-anti-semitic-scum-1.5792539) well [received](https://www.dw.com/en/israelis-fume-over-netanyahus-retraction-of-hungarys-anti-soros-campaign-criticism/a-39642016) by domestic political opponents.

Comment: Well, the middle quote is interesting; defending Soros against anti-Semitism, but not otherwise.

Comment: @user4012 The article specifically mentions criticism from "both sides of the political aisle". I think some short reference to reactions is helpful to contextualize the issue, but I can see that some more specification would be helpful. I didn't want to go into it too much though. Maybe that would make for a good separate question.

Comment: @tim - Haaretz is widely acknowledged as being a left wing publication. Unless you have neutral examples of criticizm from the right, it seems to be mainly political opposition.

Comment: @tim and DW article's "Cross-party criticism" section explicitly contradics this saying right wing figures criticize *Soros*

Comment: I'll just add - from my limited experience and knowledge - that the attacks on Soros come right out of the blue for most Israelis, who have no idea who he is and likely not heard about him before the attacks by Netanyahu senior or junior.

Comment: @einpoklum - many Israelis know. Probably, not the ones in your social circles, and ones who happen to dislike what Soros is doing - just like in US, more right wingers than left wingers know who Soros is, and the picture is reversed for Koch brothers.

Comment: @user4012: 1. Most Israelis don't know who the Koch brothers are, either. They're probably even less known than Soros, who has at least been the object of the PM's attacks. 2. How many is "many"?

Comment: @einpoklum - "**like in US**". I was making an analogy between US populace

Comment: @einpoklum - most everyone in my social circle or those whose opinions I heard online. Who understandably, share similar worldviews, echo bubbles and all.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The [Jerusalem Post reports](https://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Netanyahu-blames-Soros-for-Israel-anti-deportation-campaign-540640):

> Hungarian-American billionaire George Soros is behind the public campaign against the government’s plan to deport Sudanese and Eritrean migrants to a third country in Africa, widely believed to be Rwanda, Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu said on Sunday.
>
> Netanyahu made the comments at the weekly meeting of the Likud ministers. He also said that former US president Barack Obama “deported two million infiltrators, and no one said anything.”

Comment: The second paragraph would be worth a Skeptics' question for itself.

Comment: @Evargalo The first might be as well: Soros has denied the funding - though it's probably a question of definition. He is funding, via his foundation, left wing groups in Israel, who are protesting, but he has already done so before the protest.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to direct statemenst by Netanyahu, as mentioned in @janh's answer, there was biting criticism from his Foreign Ministry (starement by Israeli Foreign Ministry's spokesperson, Emmanuel Nahshon on July 9, 2017).

While individual Israeli ministers are known to go off the box and express personal views differing from PM, but [this was an official Minstry statement](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/PressRoom/2017/Pages/Foreign-Ministry-clarification-regarding-anti-Semitism-in-Hungary-9-July-2017.aspx) so it probably had Prime Minister's approval:

> This was the sole purpose of the statement issued by Israel’s ambassador to Hungary. **In no way was the statement meant to delegitimize criticism of George Soros, who continuously undermines Israel’s democratically elected governments by funding organizations that defame the Jewish state and seek to deny it the right to defend itself**.

---

In general, Soros is not popular among Israeli right. Netanyahu's son (not known for his polish) posted anti-Soros cartoons which caused controversy.

[This article](https://mosaicmagazine.com/picks/2017/07/what-does-israel-have-against-george-soros-quite-a-lot-actually/) in Mosaic Magazine published an extended article explaining why many Israelis dislike Soros. It's not merely the currently-flared-up issue of Soros's support for illegal aliens that Netanyahu's government wants to remove from Israel and Soros actively works against removal of.

It's general extensive support for NGOs and other organizations seen as undermining Israel, including anti-semitic ones (see the article for details).

This Bloomberg article ["A Soros Plan, a Marginalized Israel"](https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2016-08-16/how-george-soros-threatens-to-make-israel-a-pariah) details one such set of issues.

[Here's another one](https://www.algemeiner.com/2017/07/18/nine-flaws-with-new-york-times-israels-war-on-george-soros-article/) laying out grievances that many Israelis have with Soros.

Similar, Observer's piece ["Not Shocking: George Soros Funds Progressive War on Israel"](http://observer.com/2016/08/not-shocking-george-soros-funds-progressive-war-on-israel/), while it does sound like a hit piece on Soros, lays out many facts like that.

Comment: I found something even more intriguing; claim that Likud members gave Orban info to attack Soros with http://hungarianspectrum.org/2017/12/18/hungarian-anti-soros-campaign-hatched-in-jerusalem/